# How to get the current line position in the contenteditable div using javascript on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a customize editor by using contenteditable div, I need a javascript code to calculate line position of current caret position on keypress event.
Please make sure It should also work when add new line or remove a line.

**This is my contenteditable div format**

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
  <b>Heading</b>
  <br/>
  Line 1
  <br/>
  Line 2
  <br/>
  Line 3
  <br/>
  Line 4
  <br/>
  Line 5
</div>
```

Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkkgcgb0/):

Comment: No this is not duplicate. I need line position means row not col in the editable div. please read carefully my question

Comment: Simply get positions of line breaks in the text and compare to caret position?

Comment: I have already used this method but it does not work accurately.

Comment: Do you intend to take line wrapping into account?  That is, if the user types a paragraph that wraps to two lines of text, should that count as one line or two?  (If so, I believe what you want is not possible, or at least not meaningful, as it'll depend on everything from the container size to the end user's font settings.)

Comment: If you just intend to count the number of times the user hit the return key while editing the content, you could try counting tags before the current caret position -- but note that different browsers insert different HTML for that (Firefox inserts `<br></br>`, and Safari instead wraps each line in `<div>` tags for example) -- I don't think there is a standard for this, so anything you write would involve browser-sniffing and risk breakage from future browser updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<pre>` instead.

**Html**

```
<pre  contenteditable="true" id="editor">
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5</pre>

<input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add Line"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#editor').on("mouseup", function getPos() {
    var sel = document.getSelection(),
        nd = sel.anchorNode,
        text = nd.textContent.slice(0, sel.focusOffset);

    var lineNum=text.split("\n").length;
    alert(lineNum);
});

$('#addBtn').click(function(){
   var str = "new line";
   elem = document.getElementById("editor");
   elem.innerHTML =  elem.innerHTML +"\n" + str;        
});
```

I've updated my jsfiddle, and used a `pre` instead `<br/>` (for line breaks)
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ts9jooyL/7/)

Comment: This is not working correctly please look carefully

Comment: You were right. I've updated my jsfiddle, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: your code is working only on pre defined lines. Whenever add new line or drop a line then it returns wrong value.

Comment: hmmm...I just checked quickly and it is working for adding a new `pre` please see the updated Fiddle. I also updated the code above for the Addline. I'm sure it would work for remove line as well.

Comment: ya i got it. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark as answer if so, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do but I have an idea. I had a similar project where I had to take text from input boxes. I would say get an id for each paragraph or line or input box . Then add an event to the div. Once you add the event to the div, you can pretty much do anything.

Example: 
     It don't have to be body, add it to your div.

```
document.body.addEventListener("foo_event", get_target, false);

<p id="someid">Some cool stuff here or input or whatever.
 Put ids on all your lines so we can have a way to id them. Put 
classes also if you want to style them</p>

function get_target(e){
 //Some event happend let's do something

    if ("someid" === e.target.id ) {
         //Lets run some code on the paragraph or element

/*Ideally you would want an algorithm for testing ids instead of using a bunch of If statements */
     }

}
```

Comment: This is not answer of my question